# How can I fill values from duplicates in Stata?

Tags: stata, data-manipulation

The original data looks like this (`Date` is in dd/mm/yyyy format):

```
ID    Date          Var  
01    21/01/2016    1  
01    22/01/2016      
02    13/05/2016      
02    14/05/2016    2  
03    08/06/2016    3  
03    08/06/2016    4  
04    09/07/2016    5  
04    09/07/2016    
05    10/08/2016    
05    10/08/2016    6
```

In essence, for each `ID` there are three scenarios for the variable of interest `Var` in regards to the date of submission `Date`:

1/  `Var` present on the earlier `Date` but missing on the later one `(ID=01)`
2/ `Var` missing on the earlier `Date` but present on the later one `(ID=02)`
3/ `Var` present on both `Date`, whose values may be the same or different `(ID=03)`.

Now how can I modify `Var` as follows?

1/ Use value of `Var` of the earlier `Date` to fill up the later one.
2/ Use value of `Var` of the later `Date` to fill up the earlier one.
3/ Use value of `Var` of the later `Date` to replace the earlier one.

So the modified data should look like:

```
ID    Date          Var  
01    21/01/2016    1  
01    22/01/2016    1  
02    13/05/2016    2  
02    14/05/2016    2  
03    08/06/2016    4  
03    08/06/2016    4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your examples are solved by

```
bysort ID (Var): replace Var = Var[1] if missing(Var) 
bysort ID (Date): replace Var = Var[_N]
```

Replacing missing values in series using nearby known values is called interpolation. See e.g. [here](http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1308786-mipolate-now-available-from-ssc-new-program-for-interpolation) for notice of an interpolation command supporting the first method more generally (and other methods too).